# Why the binary produced by clang is larger than that's produced by visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, clang, llvm, cl

It's just a piece of "hello world" C++ code.

```
#include <stdio.h>   
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code with clang 3.9. The command is: clang -m32 hello.cpp -o hello.exe, and the target executable size is about **44kb**. It didn't make any difference with "O3" option added to the command.

While I compiled it with visual studio 2010, the size of the target executable file is only **6kb** for release version and **28kb** for debug version.

Could anyone help to explain the difference between the two versions' binary.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My crystal ball says that Clang is defaulting to statically linking the runtime libraries, whereas MSVC defaults to dynamically linking them. This means that the MSVC-generated binaries are smaller, but require an auxiliary runtime DLL. Check your compiler/linker settings to verify that this is indeed the case.

Comment: You can also try `-Oz` flag for Clang.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. Does your crystal ball know how to link the runtime libraries dynamically. I've googled without a hint.

Comment: @arrowd -Oz flag doesn't change anything. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

I use clang-cl that accepts the flag /MD instead of clang. Problem resolved. I still need to explore what's the difference between clang and clang-cl.

Comment: No idea what the native Clang flag is for dynamic linking. clang-cl is a frontend/wrapper for the Clang compiler that presents an interface compatible with MSVC's compiler, cl.exe. You're perfectly safe doing it the way you described.